# How to retrieve all the elements from a string that are present in a list

Tags: python, regex, string, list, dataframe

I have the following list and a DataFrame:

```
the_list = ["one", "et", "allu", "Metall", "54ro", 'al89']

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID':[100, 200, 300, 400],
                   'String':['Jonel-al89 (et)', 'Stel-00(et) al89 x 57-mm', 'Metall,   54ro', "allu, Metall9(lop)"]
                  })
```

What I need is to make a new column where I would get **all** the elements from the list that are present in each string in the "String" column.
So the output should be looking like that:

| ID | String | Desired_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Jonel-al89 (et) | one, al89, et |
| 200 | Stel-00(et) al89 x 57-mm | et, al89 |
| 300 | Metall, 54ro | et, Metall, 54ro |
| 400 | allu, Metall9(lop) | allu, et, Metall |

What would be the way to achieve it? 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: why is there `et` in the last row?

Comment: Because it contains in the word Metall. I need to extract it as well if it is a part of the word.

Comment: I see, however a regex can only find non overlapping elements. So do you really want this output?

Comment: Actually yes, it is hard to explain, but in the original DataFrame I need to check for the instances where a string is a part of the word as well as if it is non-overlapping. =(

Comment: Then you have to loop for all elements, unfortunately, which has a quadratic complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need regex if you use a list comprehension which checks for the presence of the elements from your list in the String column.

I'm not sure you want the elements as a list or as string, if you want a string put a [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) around the comprehension.

```py
import pandas as pd

the_list = ["one", "et", "allu", "Metall", "54ro", 'al89']

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID':[100, 200, 300, 400],
                   'String':['Jonel-al89 (et)', 'Stel-00(et) al89 x 57-mm', 'Metall,   54ro', "allu, Metall9(lop)"]
                  })

df["Desired_Column"] = df["String"].apply(lambda string: [el for el in the_list if el in string])

df
# gives
#     ID                    String      Desired_Column
# 0  100           Jonel-al89 (et)     [one, et, al89]
# 1  200  Stel-00(et) al89 x 57-mm          [et, al89]
# 2  300            Metall,   54ro  [et, Metall, 54ro]
# 3  400        allu, Metall9(lop)  [et, allu, Metall]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with a crafted regex, then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with `', '.join`:

```
import re
pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, the_list))
# 'one|et|allu|Metall|54ro|al89'

df['Desired_Column'] = (df['String'].str.extractall(f'({pattern})')[0]
                        .groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
                       )
```

Output:

```
    ID                    String Desired_Column
0  100           Jonel-al89 (et)  one, al89, et
1  200  Stel-00(et) al89 x 57-mm       et, al89
2  300            Metall,   54ro   Metall, 54ro
3  400        allu, Metall9(lop)   allu, Metall
```